# How can I automatically restart a thread Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an information synchronizer, I use a thread so that when I start the server it is executed (I use RethinkDB to listen to the changes) but when a code error occurs the thread dies, I need that when it dies it comes back and starts.

I thought about watching the thread but I have not found a solution.

In advance thank you very much for the help!

I have tried with the CRONO, but it is not an automatic solution since every so often it does the verification, the idea is that everything works in real time.

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/kostya/eye or https://github.com/mojombo/god?

Comment: your setup is not clear. whats your application server? what invokes this Thread you saying?